# Set of isolated points closed?

Tags: general-topology

$\varnothing\neq A \in 2^\mathbb R$, $A^s$ is isolated points of $A$. Is $A^s$ closed set?

notation: x is isolated point means $\exists r>0 [N(x;r)\cap A=\{x\}]$

I would like to prove but I have no idea. I'm a uni student studying the very beginning of topology. Could you help me.

Answer (score 1):

No, not necessarily, e.g. $A =\{\frac{1}{n}: n=1,2,3,\ldots\}$ has all of its points isolated, but $0 \in \overline{A}\setminus A$, so $A$ is not closed.

What *can* be said in the reals and many other spaces, is that such an $A$ is at most countable (because $\Bbb R$ is second countable).